# Converting Epoch time into the datetime

Tags: python

I am getting a response from the rest is an Epoch time format like

```
start_time = 1234566
end_time = 1234578
```

I want to convert that epoch seconds in MySQL format time so that I could store the differences in my MySQL database.

I tried:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.gmtime(123456)
time.struct_time(tm_year=1970, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=2, tm_hour=10, tm_min=17, tm_sec=36, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=2, tm_isdst=0)
```

The above result is not what I am expecting. I want it be like

```
2012-09-12 21:00:00
```

Please suggest how can I achieve this?

Also,
Why I am getting `TypeError: a float is required` for

```
>>> getbbb_class.end_time = 1347516459425
>>> mend = time.gmtime(getbbb_class.end_time).tm_hour
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: a float is required
```

Answer (score 495, accepted):

To convert your time value (float or int) to a formatted string, use:

```
strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', localtime(1347517370))
```

preceded by this import:

```
from time import strftime, localtime
```

Answer (score 306):

You can also use `datetime`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1347517370).strftime('%c')
  '2012-09-13 02:22:50'
```

Answer (score 107):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1347517370).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
'2012-09-13 14:22:50' # Local time
```

To get UTC:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1347517370).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  '2012-09-13 06:22:50'
```

Comment: For UTC, why not use `time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(1347517370))` ?

Answer (score 21):

This is what you need

```
In [1]: time.time()
Out[1]: 1347517739.44904

In [2]: time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(time.time()))
Out[2]: '2012-09-13 06:31:43'
```

Please input a `float` instead of an `int` and that other `TypeError` should go away.

```
mend = time.gmtime(float(getbbb_class.end_time)).tm_hour
```

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(1347517119))
'2012-09-12 23:18:39'
```

Also in MySQL, you can [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) like:

```
INSERT INTO tblname VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME(1347517119))
```

For your 2nd question, it is probably because `getbbb_class.end_time` is a string.  You can convert it to numeric like: `float(getbbb_class.end_time)`

Answer (score 12):

If you have epoch in milliseconds a possible solution is convert to seconds:

```
import time
time.ctime(milliseconds/1000)
```

For more `time` functions: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#functions

Answer (score 8):

```
#This adds 10 seconds from now.
from datetime import datetime
import commands

date_string_command="date +%s"
utc = commands.getoutput(date_string_command)
a_date=datetime.fromtimestamp(float(int(utc))).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print('a_date:'+a_date)
utc = int(utc)+10
b_date=datetime.fromtimestamp(float(utc)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print('b_date:'+b_date)
```

This is a little more wordy but it comes from date command in unix.

Answer (score 6):

First a bit of info in epoch from **man gmtime**

```
The ctime(), gmtime() and localtime() functions all take an argument of data type time_t which represents calendar  time.   When  inter-
       preted  as  an absolute time value, it represents the number of seconds elapsed since 00:00:00 on January 1, 1970, Coordinated Universal
       Time (UTC).
```

to understand how epoch should be.

```
>>> time.time()
1347517171.6514659
>>> time.gmtime(time.time())
(2012, 9, 13, 6, 19, 34, 3, 257, 0)
```

just ensure the arg you are passing to `time.gmtime()` is integer.

Answer (score 5):

Sharing an answer to clearly distinguish UTC and local time conversions. Use `import datetime` at the top before using the below methods.

**Convert to datetime of local machine's timezone**

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1347517370)
```

**Convert to datetime of UTC timezone**

```
datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1347517370)
```

---

For both the above methods, if you wish to return a formatted date string, use the following code block

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1347517370).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1347517370).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for a quick example,

if you want to import only `time`:

```
import time
```

current timestamp:

```
>>> time.time() # current timestamp
1702244283.169546
```

formatted string:

```
>>> time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime()) # current UTC
'2023-12-10 21:38:28'
>>> time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime()) # current local time
'2023-12-11 06:38:37'
>>> time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(1702244283.169546)) # timestamp->UTC
'2023-12-10 21:38:03'
>>> time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(1702244283.169546)) # timestamp->local time
'2023-12-11 06:38:03'
```