# Convert csv column from Epoch time to human readable minutes

Tags: python, csv, pandas, epoch

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` indexed by time, as seen below. The time is in Epoch time. When I graph the second column these time values display along the x-axis. I want a more readable time in minutes:seconds.

```
In [13]: print df.head()

Time
1481044277379    0.581858
1481044277384    0.581858
1481044277417    0.581858
1481044277418    0.581858
1481044277467    0.581858
```

I have tried some pandas functions, and some methods for converting the whole column, I visited: [Pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/timeseries.html), this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400256/) and the cool [site](http://epochconverter.com/#code).

I am using `pandas 0.18.1`

Comment: Some of the reearch i forgot to mention:
I am using pandas 0.18.1, I have read: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/timeseries.html

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400256/python-converting-epoch-time-into-the-datetime - but I dont understand what how to implement.

Comment: This online converting gives approach - http://www.epochconverter.com/#code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read your data with `read_csv` you can use a custom dateparser:

```
import pandas as pd

#example.csv
'''
Time,Value
1481044277379,0.581858 
1481044277384,0.581858
1481044277417,0.581858
1481044277418,0.581858
1481044277467,0.581858
'''

def dateparse(time_in_secs):
   time_in_secs = time_in_secs/1000
   return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(time_in_secs))

dtype= {"Time": float, "Value":float}
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv", dtype=dtype, parse_dates=["Time"], date_parser=dateparse)
print df
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped so much.

Comment: @Andrew if this answers your question you may accept the answer and close the issue, so others see it's solved. If not, please comment what's missing.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert an epoch timestamp to HH:MM with:

```
import datetime as dt
hours_mins = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(1347517370).strftime('%H:%M')
```

Adding a column to your `pandas.DataFrame` can be done as:

```
df['H_M'] = pd.Series([dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(ts)).strftime('%H:%M')
                       for ts in df['timestamp']]).values
```