# Python 2.7 strftime TypeError

Tags: python-2.7

I'm using python 2.7.x:

```
import datetime
...
def _log(error_level, message):
  try:
      d = datetime.datetime.now()
      date_template = d.strftime("%Y.%m.%d - %H:%M:%S")
      ...
  except:
      sv_custom_utils.simple_exception_info()
```

In *99%* it is running without any problems, *but sometimes* I get an error:

```
ERROR:root:
2018.11.21 - 15:58:25:
  Top:  file: [sv_logger.py], method: _log()
  Root: file: [sv_logger.py], line 51, cause: in _log [date_template = d.strftime("%Y.%m.%d - %H:%M:%S")]
  TypeError: a float is required
```

What could be a reason? Python is running on Ubuntu 16/18. Does that mean that `d` should be a float?

Comment: I don't know the cause, but this seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12400584/3000206

Comment: The code you provided is not enough to reproduce the error. Please read [how to write minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've mentioned that in 99% of the cases it will not be reproduced. That's why I've asked about it.