# Convert from datetime to epoch time (timezone aware)

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, python-datetime

I want to convert a datetime object in python 2.7, from UTC time to Unix (aka epoch) time. As far as I understand, the following should give me back the timestamp I started with (ts -> UTC -> ts):

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz
datetime.fromtimestamp(1538000000, tz.tzutc()).strftime('%s')
```

However, the output is different:
`'1537992800'`
(I am using `fromtimestamp` and not `utcfromtimestamp` as the latter returns a naive (unaware) object).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12400584/11230028 may this will help you. i think it solves your problem. So please this link once

Answer (score 0):

**This is the code though**

```
import time
time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(1347517370))
```