# request.get(url) returns date in epoch format is there a way to convert epochdate into datetime format while using request.get method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, datetime, request

I'm trying to retrive xml data from a url using python request.get(url) method. But, all the dates are in epochdate format is there a way to get the date in actual datetime format?

I tried changing the headers = {'accept': 'application/xml') and headers = {'accept': 'application/json') and request content in raw format, json,content
text formats

```
headers = {'accept': 'application/xml;odata=verbose; q=0.9, */*;q=0.8'}

val = requests.get(url, auth=HttpNtlmAuth(username, password),headers=headers, verify=False ,headers= headers)
```

val.text or val.content or val.json return the same date value in epoch format

**how date is in xml:**

2010-06-11T11:57:55

**request.get(url) returned:**

("Modified": "/Date(1276257475000)/")

any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `time.strftime` if you convert the epoch time into a number, maybe something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12400584/9032733

You could change the format of the resulting date string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @lee. But, im looking a solution to get the date in right format thorugh request.get(url) method. As the xml documents is huge one can't interate over all the variables and apply time.strftime function over them.

Comment: I don't think there exists a way to do so, besides performing any operations through `requests.get(url)` shouldn't take any less time than iterating through the xml.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert it to timestamp:
[more details of utcfromtimestamp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp)

```
import datetime
date_time = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1276257475000//1000.0)
print(date_time)
```

O/P:

```
2010-06-11 11:57:55
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions wrote a function and iterated over the json document as @LeeGarcon suggested. It worked !

```
import re
import datetime

def _epoch_to_datetime(_dict_element):
   """ This function expects a dictionary (k,v) """
   pattern = "^/Date..............."

   for k,v in _dict_element.items():
       if re.match(pattern,str(v)):
            epoch_time = v[6:-5]
            _dict_element[k] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(epoch_time)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```