# How to change path list in pandas dataframe to modification time?

Tags: python, pandas

First I have dataframe as below.

| date | time | name | type | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C:\Users\xxx\EK000059.AVI | 01:00-01:59 | \01\EK000059.AVI | Cat | 1 |
| C:\Users\xxx\EK000264.AVI | 05:00-05:59 | \05\EK000264.AVI | Cat | 1 |
| C:\Users\xxx\EK000495.AVI | 07:00-07:59 | \07\EK000495.AVI | Cat | 2 |
| C:\Users\xxx\EK000650.AVI | 07:00-07:59 | \07\EK000650.AVI | Dog | 1 |

I'd like to convert 'date' column to modification time (`getmtime`) of video files.

for example : date column from C:\Users\xxx\EK000650.AVI to 2022/05/31
and another column same as original condition.

Please recommend and supporting me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Something like `df["date"] = df["date"].apply(lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))`
Eventually, use `pd.to_datetime` if you want datetime format 

see 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-getmtime-method/ 
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: @sslloo Thank you very much for supporting me. Now I can got example time no. is 1656498242.8203564. Do you recommend me to use `pd.to_datetime` right? How to input this code to continous from `df["date"] = df["date"].apply(lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))` please recommend to me.

Comment: 1656498242.8203564. seems an absolut timestamp (time in seconds since the reference, 01-01-1970 I think), you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400256/converting-epoch-time-into-the-datetime

Comment: @sslloo I have been used `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` in general code and it's work. But I never use this code with pandas dataframe. please recommend to me If I 'd like to change `df["date"]` to date (example 2022/05/31).

Comment: @sslloo I try to use `df["date"] = df["date"].apply(lambda x : os.path.getmtime(x))` and then I use `df["date"] = df["date"].apply(lambda x : datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))` output show 2022-06-29 17:24 but It's show only 1 row. I want to show every row. Please supporting me.